# Adding text in Text Box

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I want to add text message in Text Box. When I use this method:

```
TextBox1.Text = ...
```

Previous text is cleared. Is any function which I can add text and do not clear previously?

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like...

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & ...
```

?